# How do I assign to a given combination of selectInputs() a different process for one single fileInput() in R Shiny?

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny

I've been searching all day long and I haven't find a solution to my problem, which I believe is fundamental. Also I've just been coding with shiny for two days, so I'm quite newbie in terms of web application developement.

This is the problem:

Lets say I have `selectInput1()`, `selectInput2()` and a `fileInput()`

```
library(shiny)

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Help me please"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

    selectInput("select1", "command 1",choices = c("V","W")),       # command 1
    selectInput("select2", "command 2",choices = c("a","b","c")),   # command 2

    fileInput("file", "raw", multiple = TRUE, accept = c("text/csv", ".csv") # Input
                )
               ),
    mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutpu("Final1"),     #Here I display the result 1
            verbatimTextOutpu("Final2")      # here displays the result 2

            )
               )
              )

server = function(input,output){

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Now, lets say that there are `2*3 = 6` ways (combinations) to process the `fileInput`.
lets say:

**P_{i,j}(x) := "Process i,j of x"**

where **x** is the `fileInput`, `i %in% c("V","W")` and `i %in% c("a", "b"
, "c")` choices of the selectInputs

I need a way to process in the server fileInput in a similar way as an if statement.

```
if(input$select1 == "V"){

    if(input$select2 =="a"){
        # Here goes reactiveEvent codes and complex stuff

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessVa1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessVa2())

    } else if(input$select2 == "b"){
        # Here goues reactiveEvents and ObserveEvents and crazy stuff but different

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessVb1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessVb2())

    } else if(input$select2 == "c"){
        # You get the idea

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessVc1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessVc2())
    }

} else if(input$select1 == "W"){

    if(input$select2 == "a"){

        # I hope you are getting the idea. this is being written

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessWa1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessWa2())

    } else if(input$select2 == "b"){
        # Here goues reactiveEvents and ObserveEvents and crazy stuff but different

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessWb1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessWb2())

    } else if(input$select2 == "c"){

        # You get the idea

        output$Final1 = renderPrint(subprocessWc1())
        output$Final2 = renderPrint(subprocessWc2())
    }
```

Observe that `output$Final1` and `output$Final2` will become a different output depending of the process selected (as a combination of the selectInputs)
Of course this can't be done with shiny. How could I proceed. with a switch with nested ObserveEvents and nested reactiveEvents???

Help please.

Comment: The subprocesses are quite similar, for example for subprocessWaj : `inputdata = reactive({req(input$file) #line df = read.csv(input$file$datapath) #line df }) #line inputdata.processed = eventReactive(input$button1{ prediction = predict(loaded_fitted_model_Wa1, inputdata()) # line df = data.frame(inputdata(), prediction) # line df})` And then use `inputdata()` and `inputdata.processed()` to define my `outputs`. And all that is in the server. I need to "package" that subprocess and make variations inside them (e.g. change the `fitted_model` in `predict()` in terms of my `selectInputs()`).

Comment: Yes, I could put them in a `list()`, The porpuse of the app is to select a process with the combination of the `selectInputs()` to process my data in different ways.
The truth is I have 3 `selectInputs()`. in the example W has (Wa, Wb, Wc) process and V has (Va,Vb, Vc) processes because are different datas with their own characteristics.

Comment: Thank you - see answer below, hope this might be a start to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized how to do it. I just had to use an `if()` statement flow.

What I originally had was an object in the `server` that could have different forms in terms of the different combinations of `selectInput()1` and `selectInput()2`.

I simply created the `command()` object associated to each combination of`selectInput()`,
and the object of interest which went through a different process (or transformation) in terms of the combinations of the inputs was writen in the more or less form:

```
server = function(input, output,session){

    command = reactive({
            req(input$select1)
            req(input$select2)
            paste0(input$select1,input$select2)
         })

    object1 = eventReactive(input$button{
            df = read.csv(input$file$datapath, etc etc)
        if(command() == "Wa"){

            Wa(df)  # where Wa is a transformation or function of df

        } else if(command() == "Wb"){

            Wb(df) # the next transformation

        } else if( ){   .....   }
    })

    output$trasformed.object = renderTable(object1())
}
```

Thanks to @Ben for the help.